# How can I create multiple SSH keys?

Tags: server, ssh

What would be a walkthrough on how to set up multiple SSH keys?

I'm trying to connect to my remote server and GitHub account. I've got SSH access established with GitHub, but when I used `ssh-keygen -t rsa` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, the terminal prompted me if I wanted to override the one that already exists. How can I create a new SSH key just for the remote server?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You should specify the output file, for example:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -f ~/.ssh/my-new-key
```

Then to connect:

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/my-new-key 192.168.x.x
```

Or set up an SSH configuration file:

```
nano ~/.ssh/config
```

Then put in something like:

```
Host my-server
    HostName 192.168.x.x
    User root
    Port 22
    IdentityFile /home/username/.ssh/my-new-key
```

Finally:

```
ssh my-server
```

Comment: Swell ! All I had to do is create a separate folder for the new key so it wouldn't be in conflict with the other one. Very nice ! What I don't understand though is I intentionally set the ssh key to be password-free but when I type `ssh my-server` and hit Enter I get prompted for password.

Comment: I'm not sure, make sure that `ssh-agent` is running and use `ssh-add` to add your key to key lists so it doesn't ask you for password anymore. (At this session).

Comment: I just realised that it's not a new folder what I created. I just gave it a name. I didn't know you can name a ssh key. Good to know !

Comment: Shouldn't I copy the unique ssh formula into server's ssh file of known keys ? I think it should work similar to GitHub at this regard.

Comment: You should add your new public key to your server, known hosts will be updated automatically...

Comment: Ahh that's what's missing here ....

Comment: Well I copied the public key into server's config file but didn't work. Still prompts me for password everytime I logging in. Never mind. This isn't end of the world. It's just annoying having to type in password since I'm accessing my server only from this laptop. I can live with it. I should be happy I have access to it at all. :) Cheers !

Comment: `ssh-add ~/.ssh/mynewkey` it asks your password once then you don't have to enter it again (in this session).